# Adding transform property to background-image in Styled Component

Tags: css, css-selectors, styled-components

Using Styled Components with React - I'm using props to update my properties based on their boolean values.

```
    props.isEnabled &&
    css`
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='48' height='48' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg fill='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 48h48V0H0z'/%3E%3Cpath stroke='%2327282A' stroke-linecap='round' d='m18 21 6 6 6-6'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right;
      transform: ${(props) => (props.isExpanded ? "rotate(180deg)" : "none")};
    `}
```

I have the following css that is present when `isEnabled` and I also utilise the `isExpanded` prop in an attempt to rotate the background image 180 degrees when true, however it currently flips the entire Styled Component and not just the `background-image`. can anyone suggest how I could target the `background-image` using the `isExpanded` like I do currently?

Comment: There is an example how to do it https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/Ngpvwx

Comment: Thanks for the response although the example doesn't follow the pattern used in my issue/ Styled Components in general